# Save changes after modified the style of a div from Master Page

Tags: css, asp.net

I'm new in ASP.NET and i have a little problem with dynamically changing CSS style of a div from Master Page. 
For example :

```
HtmlGenericControl DivControl = (HtmlGenericControl)this.Page.Master.FindControl("Div");

DivControl.Attributes.CssStyle.Add("height", "200px");
```

Everything works good ,but when i close my site and run  again the changes are not saved.
How can to save the changes after dynamically edit style ?
Thanks in advance and sorry form my English.

Comment: ..I think dynamic changes are lost :) So you have to edit the Style Sheet.

Comment: @Edward why do you say the changes are not saved? Please describe what happens.

Comment: For example: I have a div with height=150 px and after i change the height dynamically to 200 px and when i close and run again my site the height of div is 150 px. Thanks

Comment: But both times your page is executing that code in the master page. So you shouldn't need to save anything. What is the difference between the two times? Where in the master page do you run that code?

Comment: What action do you take to close the site and run again?

Comment: @EdwardKenway what is the solution you found?

Comment: @ Patrick , i used Magnus answer. Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you always want it, why not change the css file? Otherwise you can look into the different event handlers and put the code in the one that matches. If you put that code in your Page_Load event it will run when the page is first accessed.

Comment: Ok this i a method , but is another method ?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to dynamically change a style for a div from the MasterPage the way you are doing, be sure that you put the code in the **Render** method of your page life cycle. This will ensure that the control is present, that this one is not altered by other state of the life cycle and that this one will be executed on every request.

```
protected override void Render(HtmlTextWriter output) {
    HtmlGenericControl DivControl = (HtmlGenericControl)this.Page.Master.FindControl("Div");
    DivControl.Attributes.CssStyle.Add("height", "200px");
}
```

Comment: You should set a breakpoint and see if it is hit because this code has must be called every request is done.